# Uploading images to server from Android device

Tags: android, asp.net, web

We are currently in need of a tool to upload photos shot from an android device directly to our server without creating an android app. Can this be done in a web application? I already tried `getusermedia` API without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you can make this task simpler and more useful i have designed one class named ImageUploaderUtility, which uploads images to a remote webserver. ImageUploadUtility has simple methods where you just need to pass the name of your image to upload.

Apart from this the key point here is this class needs to be executed in an AsynTask so it ensures the whole image upload process doesn't freeze your UI.

I have used this same past project and expanded it.

The first thing to understand is i have made inner class in my BlogPostExampleActivity which is extended from AsyncTask, this inner class will call the method to upload image which is declared and defined in ImageUploader Utility that's all isn't that simple.

Have a look at the code and let me know if you can't understand anything in this.

```
private class ImageUploaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
            simpleWaitDialog = ProgressDialog.show(BlogPostExamplesActivity.this, "Wait", "Uploading Image");
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params){
            new ImageUploadUtility().uploadSingleImage(params[0]);
            return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
            simpleWaitDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

}

And Now ImageUploaderUtility.java

```
package gargi.blogpostexamples.webservice;import java.io.File;import java.io.FileInputStream;import java.io.IOException;import java.io.InputStream;import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.ByteArrayPartSource;import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.FilePart;import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.MultipartRequestEntity;import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.Part;import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.StringPart;import android.os.Environment;import android.util.Log;class ImageUploadUtility {/** * Simple Utility Method gets called from other class to start uploading the image * @param fileNameToUpload name of the file to upload */public void uploadSingleImage(String fileNameToUpload){  try {  doUploadinBackground(getBytesFromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),fileNameToUpload)), fileNameToUpload); } catch (IOException e) {  // TODO Auto-generated catch block  e.printStackTrace(); } catch (Exception e) {  // TODO Auto-generated catch block  e.printStackTrace(); }}/** * Method uploads the image using http multipart form data. * We are not using the default httpclient coming with android we are using the new from apache * they are placed in libs folder of the application * * @param imageData * @param filename * @return * @throws Exception */static boolean doUploadinBackground(final byte[] imageData, String filename) throws Exception{   String responseString = null;   PostMethod method;   method = new PostMethod("your url to upload");       org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient client = new org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient();       client.getHttpConnectionManager().getParams().setConnectionTimeout(               100000);       FilePart photo = new FilePart("userfile", new ByteArrayPartSource(           filename, imageData));       photo.setContentType("image/jpeg");       photo.setCharSet(null);       String s  =  new String(imageData);       Part[] parts = {               new StringPart("latitude", "123456"),               new StringPart("longitude","12.123567"),               new StringPart("imei","1234567899"),               new StringPart("to_email","some email"),               photo               };       method.setRequestEntity(new MultipartRequestEntity(parts, method               .getParams()));       client.executeMethod(method);       responseString = method.getResponseBodyAsString();       method.releaseConnection();       Log.e("httpPost", "Response status: " + responseString);   if (responseString.equals("SUCCESS")) {       return true;   } else {       return false;   } }/** * Simple Reads the image file and converts them to Bytes * * @param file name of the file * @return byte array which is converted from the image * @throws IOException */public static byte[] getBytesFromFile(File file) throws IOException {  InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);  // Get the size of the file  long length = file.length();  // You cannot create an array using a long type.  // It needs to be an int type.  // Before converting to an int type, check  // to ensure that file is not larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE.  if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {    // File is too large  }  // Create the byte array to hold the data  byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)length];  // Read in the bytes  int offset = 0;  int numRead = 0;  while (offset < bytes.length      && (numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0) {    offset += numRead;  }  // Ensure all the bytes have been read in  if (offset < bytes.length) {    throw new IOException("Could not completely read file "+file.getName());  }  // Close the input stream and return bytes  is.close();  return bytes;}}
```

So that's it for now, the bad thing in this is i have used to Inner Class in this activity and i don't know why but i am not feeling good about that, so next time i will try to make a single class extended from AysncTask and use that in existing examples.

Apart from this if you feel it can be improved in some other ways please don't forget to leave that in comment.

Last but not the list you can download the complete example from this [link](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BwLgnmpHGTiYZDBiNmE5MzQtZmEzMC00ZjQ0LThiZjMtNDc5M2U3YjM1NGY2).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am not totally familiar with the language though, But I did try to research using .NET. I will review and test your code ASAP. give me a few ticks!